# Etherscan SwapExactTokensForETH on Rinkby

Tags: metamask, etherscan, uniswap

I'm trying to test out swapExactTokensForETH on [Etherscan Uniswap Contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D#writeContract)

I'm trying to swap [Link](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x01be23585060835e02b77ef475b0cc51aa1e0709#writeContract) for WETH

First I approved the UniswapSmartContract using Etherscan
[image]

Then I try to call swap `swapExactTokensForETH` on the uniswap smart contract
[image]

**NOTE:** ToAddress has been redacted for security.

> When trying to execute the smart contract I get an error displayed in metamask:
> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

How can I consume the `swapExactTokensForETH` on etherscan?

Comment: What is your deadline number?! Is it for now or you added for example 100 to it!?

Comment: Turns out there is a suspiciously low amount of ether in that pool which some how causes it to throw a validation error prior to signing the call when the minOutput amount is not sufficient

Comment: Oh, it does not have enough liquidity?!